# Проблема правильного позиционирования точек прямоугольника при его повороте

Tags: javascript, svg

Ссылка: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltrmo32c/)

Используемая библиотека Raphael.js и плагин Raphael.FreeTransform.

Используемые технологии: SVG, JavaScript.

Строки:

инициализация холста: 125;

функция для перемещения точек:  260.

Проблема: Если повернуть прямоугольник на определенный угол поворота и после попробовать передвинуть точки для изменения его размера, то точки будут неправильно себя вести при перемещении.

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить данную проблему..

```js
(function(win, Raphael) {
    'use strict';

    function Paper() {
        var self = this;

        self.elementId = 'paper';
        self.width     = win.innerWidth;
        self.height    = win.innerHeight;
        self.paper     = {};
    }

    Paper.prototype.Init = function(args) {
        var self = this;
        var elementId;
        var width;
        var height;

        try {
            args = args || {};

            elementId = args.id || self.elementId;
            width     = args.width || self.width;
            height    = args.height || self.height;

            self.paper = Raphael(elementId, width, height);
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        return self;
    };

    Paper.prototype.get = function() {
        var paper = {};

        try {
            paper = this.paper;
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        return paper;
    };

    win.Paper = win.Paper || new Paper;
})(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this, Raphael);

(function(win) {
    'use strict';

    if(typeof win.Paper !== 'object') {
        return false;
    }

    function Shape() {
        var self = this;

        self.properties = {
            circleOptions : {
                fill            : '#FFD100',
                fillOpacity     : 1,
                stroke          : '#FFD100',
                strokeOpacity   : 1,
                strokeWidth     : 3,
                strokeLinecap   : 'round',
                strokeLinejoin  : 'round',
                strokeDasharray : 0
            },
            rectOptions   : {
                fill            : '#FFF20F',
                fillOpacity     : 1,
                stroke          : '#FFD103',
                strokeOpacity   : 1,
                strokeWidth     : 3,
                strokeLinecap   : 'round',
                strokeLinejoin  : 'round',
                strokeDasharray : 0
            }
        };
    }

    Shape.prototype.addPoint = function(x, y, r, properties) {
        var self    = this;
        var element = {};

        try {
            x          = x || 0;
            y          = y || 0;
            r          = r || 5;
            properties = properties || {};

            element = win.Paper.get().circle(x, y, r).attr({
                'fill'             : properties.fill || self.properties.circleOptions.fill,
                'fill-opacity'     : properties.fillOpacity || self.properties.circleOptions.fillOpacity,
                'stroke'           : properties.stroke || self.properties.circleOptions.stroke,
                'stroke-opacity'   : properties.strokeOpacity || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeOpacity,
                'stroke-width'     : properties.strokeWidth || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeWidth,
                'stroke-linecap'   : properties.strokeLinecap || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeLinecap,
                'stroke-linejoin'  : properties.strokeLinejoin || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeLinejoin,
                'stroke-dasharray' : properties.strokeDasharray || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeDasharray
            });

            element[0].setAttributeNS(null, 'id', element.id);
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        return {
            'element' : element,
            'coords'  : {
                'x' : x,
                'y' : y,
                'r' : r
            }
        };
    };

    win.Paper.Shape = new Shape();
})(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this);

(function(win) {
  var groupElements;
  var radius = 10;
  var pathData;
  var rectangle;
  var point1;
  var point2;
  var point3;
  var point4;
  var _objects = {
    'paths'  : {},
    'points' : {}
  };
  var path = {};
  var pointElements = {};
  var customizationOptions = {
    fill           : '#FFFFFF',
    fillOpacity    : 1,
    stroke         : '#000000',
    strokeOpacity  : 0.5,
    strokeWidth    : 1,
    strokeLinecap  : 'round',
    strokeLinejoin : 'round'
  };
  var freeTransformOptions          = {
    attrs     : {
      'fill'            : customizationOptions.fill,
      'fill-opacity'    : customizationOptions.fillOpacity,
      'stroke'          : customizationOptions.stroke,
      'stroke-opacity'  : customizationOptions.strokeOpacity,
      'stroke-width'    : customizationOptions.strokeWidth,
      'stroke-linecap'  : customizationOptions.strokeLinecap,
      'stroke-linejoin' : customizationOptions.strokeLinejoin
    },
    draw      : [],
    distance  : 0,
    drag      : [],
    keepRatio : [],
    range     : {
      rotate : [-180, 180],
      scale  : [-99999, 99999]
    },
    rotate    : [],
    scale     : [],
    size      : 0,
    snap      : {
      drag   : 0,
      rotate : 0,
      scale  : 0
    },
    snapDist  : {
      drag   : 0,
      rotate : 0,
      scale  : 0
    }
  };
  var freeTransformObj;
  var resizeModule;
  
  // style options
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeOpacity                = 0.5;
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.fillOpacity                  = 0.2;
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.circleOptions.radius                     = 10;
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.circleOptions.strokeWidth                = 0;
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.circleOptions.fillOpacity                = 0.7;
  
  // rotate options
  freeTransformOptions.distance = 1.3;
  freeTransformOptions.size     = 5;
  freeTransformOptions.rotate   = ['axisX', 'axisY'];

  win.Paper.Init({
    id     : 'paper',
    width  : 1024,
    height : 1024
  });
  
  pathData = [['M', 105, 105], ['L', 250, 105], ['L', 250, 150], ['L', 105, 150], ['Z']];
  rectangle = win.Paper.get().path(pathData).attr({
    'fill'             : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.fill,
    'fill-opacity'     : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.fillOpacity,
    'stroke'           : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.stroke,
    'stroke-opacity'   : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeOpacity,
    'stroke-width'     : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeWidth,
    'stroke-linecap'   : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeLinecap,
    'stroke-linejoin'  : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeLinejoin,
    'stroke-dasharray' : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeDasharray
 });
  point1 = win.Paper.Shape.addPoint(pathData[0][1], pathData[0][2], radius).element;
  point2 = win.Paper.Shape.addPoint(pathData[1][1], pathData[1][2], radius).element;
  point3 = win.Paper.Shape.addPoint(pathData[2][1], pathData[2][2], radius).element;
  point4 = win.Paper.Shape.addPoint(pathData[3][1], pathData[3][2], radius).element;
  
  groupElements = win.Paper.get().set();
  groupElements.push(rectangle);
  groupElements.push(point1);
  groupElements.push(point2);
  groupElements.push(point3);
  groupElements.push(point4);
  
  for(var key in groupElements) {
    if(groupElements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(groupElements[key].type === 'path') {
        path['element'] = groupElements[key];

        _objects.paths[groupElements[key].id] = {
          path          : path,
          pointElements : pointElements
        };
      }
      else {
        if(groupElements[key].type === 'circle') {
          pointElements[groupElements[key].id] = {
            path         : path,
            pointElement : groupElements[key],
            index        : key - 1
          };

          _objects.points[groupElements[key].id] = pointElements[groupElements[key].id];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  freeTransformObj =  win.Paper.get().freeTransform(groupElements, freeTransformOptions);
  resizeModule = new resize();
  
  groupElements.drag(function onmove(dx, dy, x, y, event) {
    resizeModule.move(dx, dy);
  }, function onstart(x, y, event) {
    resizeModule.start(x, y, event);
  }, function onend(event) {
    resizeModule.end(event);
  });
  
  function resize() {
   var pathElement  = {};
    var currentElement;
    var path         = [];
    var index        = 0;
    var pointElement = {};
    var posX         = 0;
    var posY         = 0;

    this.start = function(x, y, event) {
      if(currentElement = event.target || event.srcElement) {
        if(_objects.points[currentElement.id]) {
          pointElement = _objects.points[currentElement.id].pointElement;
          pathElement  = _objects.points[pointElement.id].path.element;
          index        = _objects.points[pointElement.id].index;

          posX = pointElement.attrs.cx;
          posY = pointElement.attrs.cy;

          path   = pathElement.getPath();
        }
      }
    };

    this.move = function(dx, dy) {
      var x           = 0;
      var y           = 0;
      var pointElements;
      var bbox;
      var middlePoint = {};
      var point;

      if(currentElement.nodeName === 'circle' && path.length) {
        x = posX + dx;
        y = posY + dy;
        
        pointElement.attr({cx : x});
        path[index][1] = x;

        pointElement.attr({cy : y});
        path[index][2] = y;

        pathElement.attr({
          path : path
        });
      }
    };

    this.end = function(event) {};
  }
})(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this);
```

```css
#paper {
  min-height : 768px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.8/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="https://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/raphael.free_transform/raphael.free_transform.js"></script>

<div id="paper"></div>
```

Comment: код лучше добавить в вопрос

Comment: а если не поворачивать? я как-то разницы не понял

Comment: Нужно поворачивать. Это фрагмент кода с моего инструмента одного, где должна быть возможность вращать элемент и изменять его размеры.

Comment: Если угол поворота фигуры = 0, то позиционирование точек на его углах происходит правильно, но стоит только повернуть объект, матрица объекта перерасчитывается и точки уже неправильно позиционируются..

Comment: Не поможет. Там что-то нужно с матричными преобразованиями сделать, вот только не понимаю что и как правильно сделать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае с поворотом координата при перемещении мышью зависит от обоих смещений(по X и по Y), необходимо учесть угол поворота, как то так:

```
this.move = function(dx, dy) {
    ...
    let angle = groupElements.freeTransform.attrs.rotate/180*Math.PI;
    y = posY + dy*Math.cos(angle) - dx*Math.sin(angle);
    x = posX + dy*Math.sin(angle) + dx*Math.cos(angle);
    ...
}
```

```js
(function(win, Raphael) {
    'use strict';

    function Paper() {
        var self = this;

        self.elementId = 'paper';
        self.width     = win.innerWidth;
        self.height    = win.innerHeight;
        self.paper     = {};
    }

    Paper.prototype.Init = function(args) {
        var self = this;
        var elementId;
        var width;
        var height;

        try {
            args = args || {};

            elementId = args.id || self.elementId;
            width     = args.width || self.width;
            height    = args.height || self.height;

            self.paper = Raphael(elementId, width, height);
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        return self;
    };

    Paper.prototype.get = function() {
        var paper = {};

        try {
            paper = this.paper;
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        return paper;
    };

    win.Paper = win.Paper || new Paper;
})(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this, Raphael);

(function(win) {
    'use strict';

    if(typeof win.Paper !== 'object') {
        return false;
    }

    function Shape() {
        var self = this;

        self.properties = {
            circleOptions : {
                fill            : '#FFD100',
                fillOpacity     : 1,
                stroke          : '#FFD100',
                strokeOpacity   : 1,
                strokeWidth     : 3,
                strokeLinecap   : 'round',
                strokeLinejoin  : 'round',
                strokeDasharray : 0
            },
            rectOptions   : {
                fill            : '#FFF20F',
                fillOpacity     : 1,
                stroke          : '#FFD103',
                strokeOpacity   : 1,
                strokeWidth     : 3,
                strokeLinecap   : 'round',
                strokeLinejoin  : 'round',
                strokeDasharray : 0
            }
        };
    }

    Shape.prototype.addPoint = function(x, y, r, properties) {
        var self    = this;
        var element = {};

        try {
            x          = x || 0;
            y          = y || 0;
            r          = r || 5;
            properties = properties || {};

            element = win.Paper.get().circle(x, y, r).attr({
                'fill'             : properties.fill || self.properties.circleOptions.fill,
                'fill-opacity'     : properties.fillOpacity || self.properties.circleOptions.fillOpacity,
                'stroke'           : properties.stroke || self.properties.circleOptions.stroke,
                'stroke-opacity'   : properties.strokeOpacity || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeOpacity,
                'stroke-width'     : properties.strokeWidth || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeWidth,
                'stroke-linecap'   : properties.strokeLinecap || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeLinecap,
                'stroke-linejoin'  : properties.strokeLinejoin || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeLinejoin,
                'stroke-dasharray' : properties.strokeDasharray || self.properties.circleOptions.strokeDasharray
            });

            element[0].setAttributeNS(null, 'id', element.id);
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        return {
            'element' : element,
            'coords'  : {
                'x' : x,
                'y' : y,
                'r' : r
            }
        };
    };

    win.Paper.Shape = new Shape();
})(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this);

(function(win) {
  var groupElements;
  var radius = 10;
  var pathData;
  var rectangle;
  var point1;
  var point2;
  var point3;
  var point4;
  var _objects = {
    'paths'  : {},
    'points' : {}
  };
  var path = {};
  var pointElements = {};
  var customizationOptions = {
    fill           : '#FFFFFF',
    fillOpacity    : 1,
    stroke         : '#000000',
    strokeOpacity  : 0.5,
    strokeWidth    : 1,
    strokeLinecap  : 'round',
    strokeLinejoin : 'round'
  };
  var freeTransformOptions          = {
    attrs     : {
      'fill'            : customizationOptions.fill,
      'fill-opacity'    : customizationOptions.fillOpacity,
      'stroke'          : customizationOptions.stroke,
      'stroke-opacity'  : customizationOptions.strokeOpacity,
      'stroke-width'    : customizationOptions.strokeWidth,
      'stroke-linecap'  : customizationOptions.strokeLinecap,
      'stroke-linejoin' : customizationOptions.strokeLinejoin
    },
    draw      : [],
    distance  : 0,
    drag      : [],
    keepRatio : [],
    range     : {
      rotate : [-180, 180],
      scale  : [-99999, 99999]
    },
    rotate    : [],
    scale     : [],
    size      : 0,
    snap      : {
      drag   : 0,
      rotate : 0,
      scale  : 0
    },
    snapDist  : {
      drag   : 0,
      rotate : 0,
      scale  : 0
    }
  };
  var freeTransformObj;
  var resizeModule;
  
  // style options
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeOpacity                = 0.5;
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.fillOpacity                  = 0.2;
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.circleOptions.radius                     = 10;
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.circleOptions.strokeWidth                = 0;
  win.Paper.Shape.properties.circleOptions.fillOpacity                = 0.7;
  
  // rotate options
  freeTransformOptions.distance = 1.3;
  freeTransformOptions.size     = 5;
  freeTransformOptions.rotate   = ['axisX', 'axisY'];

  win.Paper.Init({
    id     : 'paper',
    width  : 1024,
    height : 1024
  });
  
  pathData = [['M', 105, 105], ['L', 250, 105], ['L', 250, 150], ['L', 105, 150], ['Z']];
  rectangle = win.Paper.get().path(pathData).attr({
    'fill'             : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.fill,
    'fill-opacity'     : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.fillOpacity,
    'stroke'           : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.stroke,
    'stroke-opacity'   : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeOpacity,
    'stroke-width'     : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeWidth,
    'stroke-linecap'   : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeLinecap,
    'stroke-linejoin'  : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeLinejoin,
    'stroke-dasharray' : win.Paper.Shape.properties.rectOptions.strokeDasharray
 });
  point1 = win.Paper.Shape.addPoint(pathData[0][1], pathData[0][2], radius).element;
  point2 = win.Paper.Shape.addPoint(pathData[1][1], pathData[1][2], radius).element;
  point3 = win.Paper.Shape.addPoint(pathData[2][1], pathData[2][2], radius).element;
  point4 = win.Paper.Shape.addPoint(pathData[3][1], pathData[3][2], radius).element;
  
  groupElements = win.Paper.get().set();
  groupElements.push(rectangle);
  groupElements.push(point1);
  groupElements.push(point2);
  groupElements.push(point3);
  groupElements.push(point4);
  
  for(var key in groupElements) {
    if(groupElements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(groupElements[key].type === 'path') {
        path['element'] = groupElements[key];

        _objects.paths[groupElements[key].id] = {
          path          : path,
          pointElements : pointElements
        };
      }
      else {
        if(groupElements[key].type === 'circle') {
          pointElements[groupElements[key].id] = {
            path         : path,
            pointElement : groupElements[key],
            index        : key - 1
          };

          _objects.points[groupElements[key].id] = pointElements[groupElements[key].id];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  freeTransformObj =  win.Paper.get().freeTransform(groupElements, freeTransformOptions);
  resizeModule = new resize();
  
  groupElements.drag(function onmove(dx, dy, x, y, event) {
    resizeModule.move(dx, dy);
  }, function onstart(x, y, event) {
    resizeModule.start(x, y, event);
  }, function onend(event) {
    resizeModule.end(event);
  });
  
  function resize() {
   var pathElement  = {};
    var currentElement;
    var path         = [];
    var index        = 0;
    var pointElement = {};
    var posX         = 0;
    var posY         = 0;

    this.start = function(x, y, event) {
      if(currentElement = event.target || event.srcElement) {
        if(_objects.points[currentElement.id]) {
          pointElement = _objects.points[currentElement.id].pointElement;
          pathElement  = _objects.points[pointElement.id].path.element;
          index        = _objects.points[pointElement.id].index;

          posX = pointElement.attrs.cx;
          posY = pointElement.attrs.cy;

          path   = pathElement.getPath();
        }
      }
    };

    this.move = function(dx, dy) {
      var x           = 0;
      var y           = 0;
      var pointElements;
      var bbox;
      var middlePoint = {};
      var point;

      if(currentElement.nodeName === 'circle' && path.length) {
        let angle = groupElements.freeTransform.attrs.rotate/180*Math.PI;
    
        y = posY + dy*Math.cos(angle) - dx*Math.sin(angle);
        x = posX + dy*Math.sin(angle) + dx*Math.cos(angle);
        
        pointElement.attr({cx : x});
        path[index][1] = x;

        pointElement.attr({cy : y});
        path[index][2] = y;

        pathElement.attr({
          path : path
        });
      }
    };

    this.end = function(event) {};
  }
})(typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : this);
```

```css
#paper {
  min-height : 768px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.8/raphael.js"></script>
<script src="https://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/raphael.free_transform/raphael.free_transform.js"></script>

<div id="paper"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение :)

Comment: Это решение решило мою проблему. Очень долго бился над ней. Спасибо тебе :)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q `cos(angle+PI/2) === -sin(angle), sin(angle+PI/2) === cos(angle)`

Comment: @MBo ну да, как в матрице поворота

Comment: Да, это она и есть

Comment: Уже готовые синус и косинус лежат в матрице преобразований `pathElement.matrix`. Там 6 элементов - `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` и `f`. Из них `a = d = cos(angle)` и `b = - c = sin(angle)`. То есть, синус можно поменять на `pathElement.matrix.b`, а косинус на `pathElement.matrix.a`.
https://code-industry.ru/masterpdfeditor-help/transformation-matrix/

Comment: @GlebKemarsky прекрасное дополнение, но я не знал и незнаю эту либу :), наверняка и умножение вектора на матрицу есть :)